# Is it correct to use "Please find in the following"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

I'm writing an article. At the beginning of the article, I want to write this quick introduction:

> We are pleased to share with you our knowledge in the network device
>   managements. Please find in the following our experience in the RFCXXX
>   implementation.

I'm wondering if the usage of "Please find in the following" is correct in the above introduction?

Comment: What does the word "following" refer to?  An attachment to an email?  An enclosure in the envelope of a letter?  A paragraph in an email or a letter?  A blurb from an article (enclosed in the envelope) from a trade magazine that cites your work in network-device management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the above sentence sounds okay. Or otherwise what sounds okay to me is:

> We are pleased to share, our knowledge in network device management,
>   with you. Please, find in the following, our experience in the RFCXXX
>   implementation.

Comment: The word ***Please*** is associated with ***find***, so there should be no comma between the two words: ***Please find ...***. Having removed that comma, there should be no comma after ***following***. If you were to remove the clause in parathesis (i.e. between the commas), it would read ***Please our experience ...***., which is clearly incorrect.  I would also omit both commas in the first sentence, otherwise you are separating verb from object ***share our knowledge***.

Comment: Sorry.  Can't agree with you.  Your first sentence sounds stilted and unnatural.  Better:  "We are pleased to share our knowledge in network-device management."  As for the second sentence, the notion of "finding" reminds me of the words commonly found in old-fashioned letters:  "Enclosed please find . . ." (as if the receiver of the letter would have to search high and low in the envelope for an enclosure; no, just "enclosed is").  The OP needs to provide more information, so as to reveal what exactly the "following" is.  Is it an enclosure?  Is it a section in an email?

Answer (score 2):

In the first sentence ***the*** network device **managements** is not correct.  As @AnandS indicated, this should read:

> *We are pleased to share our knowledge in network device **management***

(The *with you* is unnecessary.)

The second sentence is not 'wrong', but I find it very stilted. Better, would be something along the lines:

> *Our experience in the implementation of R... is described* (or *discussed*) *below.*